# Validator in a laravel package

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-validation

I'm trying to use the **Validator** inside my Laravel package. From the service provider Im sending the validator as a constructor parameter to the Exam class but I'm getting this error

```
Object of class Illuminate\Validation\Factory could not be converted to string
```

Below is my service provider register function:

```
public function register()
    {
        $this->app['exam'] = $this->app->share(function($app)
        {
            return new Exam($this->app['session.store'],$this->app['validator']);
        });
    }
```

and the Exam constructor where the error is generating from:

```
public function __construct(SessionStore $session, Validator $validator) 
    {
        $this->session = $session;
        $this->container = 'Testum_Exam';
        $this->$validator = $validator;
        $this->initializeExam();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in this string `$this->$validator = $validator;`

Need   `$this->validator = $validator;`

Comment: OMG How did I not see that! Thank you so much :) :)